# Icelandic letters in \label & \cite NOT in \section{}, \chapter{}

Tags: texstudio

I did what T.Pluess suggested, and found out that the problem is in `\label{Icelandic letters}` and also in `\cite{Icel.letters}`, so I have been going through my file and it is working.

---

I just upgraded the TexStudio and now I get error's that I didn´t have few weeks ago.

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. ...}{{1}{9}{Borðspil á Íslandi}{chapter.1}{}}
...
Missing \endcsname inserted. ...Mylla og Færingatafl}{subsection.1.1.3}{}}

\chapter{Borðspil á Íslandi}
\label{sec:BordspilAIslandi}
..
\subsection{Mylla og Færingatafl}
\label{sec:MyllaOgFaeringatafl}
```

It seems only to affect Icelandic letters like Þ,þ,Æ,æ,Ð,ð

I have these commands in the tex-file

```
\usepackage[english,icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Does the error go away when you delete the temporary (`.aux`) file? Can you double-check that your file is actually `latin1` (ISO 8859-1) encoded?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the file is saved in latin1, this is not the default in texstudio. It tells you the encoding in the lower right part of the texstudio frame.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There are no need of thanks in this site (nor signature since your username is added automatically). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Indent your code 4 spaces or use the Code Sample button **`{}`** to format it correctly.

Comment: In the status bar of TeXstudio, change the encoding to UTF and change the option in `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 1):

I made the experience that I always had the least problems with special characters (german umlauts etc.) if I use UTF8 encoding. I previously also used ISO-8859-1, but it has the disadvantage that with many text editors, you need to configure this type of encoding explicitly, which is not the case if you use UTF8 because this seems to be the default for most text editors.

Therefore, this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
    \section{Section Þ,þ,Æ,æ,Ð,ð }

    \subsection{Mylla og Færingatafl}

    Þ,þ,Æ,æ,Ð,ð 

\end{document}
```

works perfectly fine on my box and should also on yours. Just make sure that the `.tex` file is indeed encoded with UTF8.